# Assigning methods to object at run-time - Design Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, properties, lazy-loading

I have created an architecture in my C# code which does exactly what I want, but seems it would be very difficult to maintain in the long-run and am **hoping** there's a design pattern / better architecture I could be pointed towards.

I have created an object `Test` which, again, does exactly what I need perfectly which has the following structure:

```
class Test
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Func<Test, object>> MethodDictionary;

    public double Var1;
    public double Var2;

    private Lazy<object> _test1;
    public object Test1 { get { return _test1.Value; } }

    private Lazy<object> _test2;
    public object Test2 { get { return _test2.Value; } }

    public Test()
    {
        _test1 = new Lazy<object>(() => MethodDictionary["Test1"](this), true);
        _test2 = new Lazy<object>(() => MethodDictionary["Test2"](this), true);
    }
}
```

What this allows me to do is, at run-time to assign a dictionary of functions to my `Test` object and the 2 properties `Test1` & `Test2` will use the functions loaded into it to return values.

The implementation looking somewhat as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Func<Test, object>> MethodDictionary = new Dictionary<string,Func<Test,object>>();
        MethodDictionary.Add("Test1", TestMethod1);
        MethodDictionary.Add("Test2", TestMethod2);

        Test.MethodDictionary = MethodDictionary;

        var x = new Test() { Var1 = 20, Var2 = 30 };
        Console.WriteLine(x.Test1.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(x.Test2.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static object TestMethod1(Test t)
    { return t.Var1 + t.Var2; }

    private static object TestMethod2(Test t)
    { return t.Var1 - t.Var2; }

}
```

And it works great and has proven very efficient for large sets of `Test` objects.

My challenge is that if I ever want to add in a new method to my `Test` class, I need to add in the:

1. `private Lazy<object> _myNewMethod;`
2. `public object MyNewMethod { get { return _myNewMethod.Value; } }`
3. Update the constuctor with the key to look for in the dictionary

And, although that is pretty simple, I'd love to have a 1-line add-in (maybe some form of custom object) or have the properties read directly form the dictionary without any need for defining them at all.

Any ideas? ANY help would be great!!!

Thanks!!!

Comment: I'd say the first problem is that you've got mutable global state (and via a public field, too). That really doesn't sound like a good idea to me. What is this `Test` class really meant to represent? It sounds like maybe you're writing a quick and dirty dependency injection framework - in which case I'd recommend using a proper one instead...

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for the input - What I'm trying to do is to have a set of "rules" stored as text in a DB, that will be read in and parsed into functions at run-time and set as methods on the `Test` object. Then to compute information / outputs (based upon those rules) on a large `List<Test>` . Does that make sense?

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for either `ExpandoObject` or `DynamicObject`.  ["Represents an object whose members can be dynamically added and removed at run time"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx)  Or perhaps these objects should be made using a prototype-based language like Javascript (which also can be hosted on .NET).

Comment: @BenVoigt, I looked into `ExpandoObject`s, but didn't really manage to figure out how to get what I anted to do here using them... any ideas??

Comment: Have you looked at the class design for JUnit 3.8.1? There are lots of design patterns used there: http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookstour/cookstour.htm NUnit is a .NET analog, although I've never checked to see if it follows the same pattern structure.

Comment: I started on an answer, but there is something that does not make sense to me from the example you provided. Your `TestMethod1` for example returns the sum of the **current** instance values of `Var1` and `Var2`, in your sample configuration, once `Test1` is invoked, its (lazy) value will be set to this sum. Now, if `Var1` or `Var2` were to change, and later on `Test1` is invoked again, it will return the initial sum value that was assigned to the `_test1` lazy instance at the first invocation. This will not match the new sum of `Var1` and `Var2`. Could you expand on your intended usage?

Comment: @Alex , you are correct.... The intended usage is that I am getting a very large dataset back from a database with each object having, say, 15 set characteristics. What I want is to have these formula "rules" external to my code and, for each of these objects to be able to calculate the dynamic properties based upon these rules... For each object, once a property is calculated, it will not change (since the 15 characteristic inputs stay the same) - I just need to figure out its value for, either (1) being an input for another dynamic property or (2) to send upstream... Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways in which you could achieve your desired behavior, is to use something that resembles a miniature IoC framework for field injection, tuned to your specific use case.

To make things easier, allow less typing in your concrete classes and make things type-safe, we introduce the `LazyField` type:

```
public class LazyField<T>
{
    private static readonly Lazy<T> Default = new Lazy<T>();
    private readonly Lazy<T> _lazy;

    public LazyField() : this(Default) { }
    public LazyField(Lazy<T> lazy)
    {
        _lazy = lazy;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _lazy.Value.ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator T(LazyField<T> instance)
    {
        return instance._lazy.Value;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, we define an abstract base class, that ensures that these fields will be created at construction time:

```
public abstract class AbstractLazyFieldHolder
{
    protected AbstractLazyFieldHolder()
    {
        LazyFields.BuildUp(this); // ensures fields are populated.
    }
}
```

Skipping for a moment how this is achieved (explained further below), this allows the following way of defining your `Test` class:

```
public class Test : AbstractLazyFieldHolder
{
    public double Var1;
    public double Var2;
    public readonly LazyField<double> Test1;
    public readonly LazyField<double> Test2;
}
```

Note that these fields are immutable, initialized in the constructor. Now, for your usage example, the below snippet shows the "new way" of doing this:

```
LazyFields.Configure<Test>()
    // We can use a type-safe lambda
    .SetProvider(x => x.Test1, inst => inst.Var1 + inst.Var2)
    // Or the field name.
    .SetProvider("Test2", TestMethod2);

var x = new Test() { Var1 = 20, Var2 = 30 };
Console.WriteLine(x.Test1);
double test2Val = x.Test2; // type-safe conversion
Console.WriteLine(test2Val);

// Output:
// 50
// -10
```

The class below provides the services that support the configuration and injection of these field value.

```
public static class LazyFields
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IBuildUp> _registry = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type,IBuildUp>();

    public interface IConfigureType<T> where T : class
    {
        IConfigureType<T> SetProvider<FT>(string fieldName, Func<T, FT> provider);
        IConfigureType<T> SetProvider<F, FT>(Expression<Func<T, F>> fieldExpression, Func<T, FT> provider) where F : LazyField<FT>;
    }

    public static void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(instance != null);
        var builder = _registry.GetOrAdd(instance.GetType(), BuildInitializer);
        builder.BuildUp(instance);
    }

    public static IConfigureType<T> Configure<T>() where T : class
    {
        return (IConfigureType<T>)_registry.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), BuildInitializer);
    }

    private interface IBuildUp 
    {
        void BuildUp(object instance);
    }

    private class TypeCfg<T> : IBuildUp, IConfigureType<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly List<FieldInfo> _fields;
        private readonly Dictionary<string, Action<T>> _initializers;

        public TypeCfg()
        {
            _fields = typeof(T)
                .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                .Where(IsLazyField)
                .ToList();
            _initializers = _fields.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, BuildDefaultSetter);
        }

        public IConfigureType<T> SetProvider<FT>(string fieldName, Func<T,FT> provider) 
        {
            var pi = _fields.First(x => x.Name == fieldName);
            _initializers[fieldName] = BuildSetter<FT>(pi, provider);
            return this;
        }

        public IConfigureType<T> SetProvider<F,FT>(Expression<Func<T,F>> fieldExpression, Func<T,FT> provider) 
            where F : LazyField<FT>
        {
            return SetProvider((fieldExpression.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name, provider);
        }

        public void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            var typedInstance = (T)instance;
            foreach (var initializer in _initializers.Values)
                initializer(typedInstance);
        }

        private bool IsLazyField(FieldInfo fi)
        {
            return fi.FieldType.IsGenericType && fi.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(LazyField<>);
        }

        private Action<T> BuildDefaultSetter(FieldInfo fi)
        {
            var itemType = fi.FieldType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var defValue = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(LazyField<>).MakeGenericType(itemType));
            return (inst) => fi.SetValue(inst, defValue);
        }

        private Action<T> BuildSetter<FT>(FieldInfo fi, Func<T, FT> provider)
        {
            return (inst) => fi.SetValue(inst, new LazyField<FT>(new Lazy<FT>(() => provider(inst))));
        }
    }

    private static IBuildUp BuildInitializer(Type targetType)
    {
        return (IBuildUp)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TypeCfg<>).MakeGenericType(targetType));
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW, Alex!!!... Just !!WOW!! - I'm going through it now.... What I'm seeing as an issue, but I might just be doing something wrong is that I keep having an issue with `.SetProvider("Total", TestMethod2)` - When I include that (and I do have a method as stated in my original question), I get an ArgumentException error at the line: `private Action<T> BuildSetter<FT> ...
                return (inst) => fi.SetValue(inst, new LazyField<FT>(new Lazy<FT>(() => provider(inst))));` -

Comment: I'm still playing with it, though - Probably something on my end... But... Just !!WOW!!

Comment: as expected... I was wrong... Your answer works **PERFECTLY** - THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Look at library https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface. 
With it and using DynamicObject i wrote sample code that shows how to simplify adding new methods:

```
public class Methods
{
    public Methods()
    {
        MethodDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Func<ITest, object>>();
        LazyObjects = new Dictionary<string, Lazy<object>>();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, Func<ITest, object>> MethodDictionary { get; private set; }

    public Dictionary<string, Lazy<object>> LazyObjects { get; private set; }
}

public class Proxy : DynamicObject
{
    Methods _methods;
    public Proxy()
    {
        _methods = new Methods();
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = _methods.LazyObjects[binder.Name].Value;            

        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        _methods.MethodDictionary[binder.Name] = (Func<ITest, object>)value;
        _methods.LazyObjects[binder.Name] = new Lazy<object>(() => _methods.MethodDictionary[binder.Name](this.ActLike<ITest>()), true);
        return true;                        
    }

}

//now you can add new methods by add single method to interface 
public interface ITest
{
    object Test1 { get; set; }
    object Test2 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new Proxy().ActLike<ITest>();

        x.Test1 = new Func<ITest, object>((y) => "Test1");
        x.Test2 = new Func<ITest, object>((y) => "Test2");


        Console.WriteLine(x.Test1);
        Console.WriteLine(x.Test2);
    }
}
```

Comment: !!WOW!! - I'm still trying to work my way through this, but I'm seeing that this really does solve the problem. Based upon this architecture, though, every property of `ITest` must be of the form of a `Func<ITest, object>`, right? There is no way to have some methods that are simply, say `double prop1; bool prop2;` etc? That, say, `Test1`, `Test2` would just use in their calculations, but are set without the need for lambdas? - Does that make sense?

Comment: Just to explain, what I'm looking to have is that a certain set of values on my object are returned from, say, a database and, then, the remaining set are set using the functions as you have described above... then I can loop through my long list of objects and get the calculated values which were based upon rules... I hope that explains my use-case....

Comment: You can add this Props to interface ITest and then check type of parameter value in Proxy.TrySetMember and decide how to process it's value. For example if value isn't a function then just save it's as value in dictionary and return value on TryGetMember

Comment: Thank you - I got it working based upon your suggestion, but it, unfortunately, doesn't seem to meet my needs... My challenge is that I was looking for a way to add the functions **once** for my class of object (see my question) and, then, have the value from that function be re-computed for each implementation of that object in my list... It seems that with your solution, I have to add this function for each object separately... I **hope** that makes sense... If you can see a way to make it work, PLEASE let me know, but I have to say that your answer is still ingenious in my books!!!

Comment: Oleg, I truly can't thank you enough for your answer and am still looking for a way to offer you a bounty too as it really is great knowledge you have shared! - However, Alex's answer matched my question exactly and met my exact needs, so I marked hos as the solution... I truly can not thank you enough, though!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but I think you can use a simpler approach like this:

```
class Test
{
  public static Dictionary<string, Func<Test, object>> MethodDictionary;
  public double Var1;
  public double Var2;
}
```

Calling the function is simple:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, Func<Test, object>> MethodDictionary = new Dictionary<string,Func<Test,object>>();
    MethodDictionary.Add("Test1", TestMethod1);
    MethodDictionary.Add("Test2", TestMethod2);

    Test.MethodDictionary = MethodDictionary;

    var x = new Test() { Var1 = 20, Var2 = 30 };
    Console.WriteLine(Test.MethodDictionary["Test1"](x).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(Test.MethodDictionary["Test2"](x).ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Huy - The challenge with that is that you can't have nested functions - What I mean is that, given that architecture, you can have `X.Test1` be called from `X.Test2` - But thanks!!